# How to build a Regular Expression for while loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, interpreter

I am trying to build a regular expresion for `while` loop to include in my program. This is what I have come up with so far:

https://regex101.com/r/aL0zC7/1[1](https://regex101.com/r/aL0zC7/1)

```
/^ *while +\( *([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*) *([=<>]) *([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*|[0-9]+) *\) *$/
```

But the problem is that I want the condition to include

```
==, <, >, <=,>=
```

in order to test `(a==5)` or `(a<=5)` or `(a>=5)`, and not only  `=,<,>`. I tried adding the following pattern into my expresion: `([=<>])`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why not just something like `(=|==|<=|>=)`?  Also, why does your test string have '=' when you're looking to add '==' as the equality comparator?

Comment: @ ray thanks a lot. In act I dont want to test them for`=` but i didnt  know how to make it for `==` thats why i put it there

Comment: You're welcome.  I should note that there are plenty of other ways to write that part, like `[=<>]+` or `[=<>]`{1,2}, but these will "overmatch", catching strings like `===` or `=<`.  Listing all the exact possibilities in a group with alternation -- `(possibility1|possibility2|etc)` -- is more precise _and_ more legible.

Comment: @Ray: `(=|==|<=|>=)` will not work as expected, as regex engine will read from left to right, and match `=` in `==`. So, `==` must come earlier. Also, when we have a full list, we can always make it shorter, why list everything if we have *patterns*?

Comment: @stribizhev Thank you for your input.  `(=|==|<=|>=)` actually does work, I recommend you test it.  Using an "unrolled" list improves legibility -- this was explained.  Yes, `[=<>]=?` also matches exactly the possibilities we seek, but we should be careful not to use hard-to-read expressions because we can and it's fun, when we also value being able to easily read code.  I don't think the objective is "shorter" as much as "more readable".  I've had to interpret enough of my own regexes, coming back to them long after having written them, to know that being clever isn't being very clever.

Comment: @Ray: As I said, this regex will match just `=` in `==`: https://regex101.com/r/fX9kG2/1. It should be in different order: https://regex101.com/r/fX9kG2/2

Comment: @stribizhev thanks  for your help. I solve it now. But if it is possible for you could you help me with my other problem? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30006376/how-to-make-print-statement-to-print-multiple-strings-javascript) Thanks in advance

Comment: @orsina, I commend you on your boldness, writing an interpreter.  I hope you learn a lot in the process.  Another, efficient way to learn about them may be to study textbooks about compiler and interpreter construction.

Comment: @stribizhev, I see now your meaning.  You are right that alone it matches the "wrong" text.  This regex works in the _context_ of the whole pattern:  [`\s*while\s+\(\s*([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)\s*(=|==|<=|>=)\s*([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*|[0-9]+)\s*`](https://regex101.com/r/qQ0zX6/1).  But maybe making that portion (just `(=|==|<=|>=)`) work if removed from its context would be a good general behavior.  Thanks for the inspiration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex will match all of the cases:

```
 *while +\( *([a-z]\w*) *([=<>]=?) *([a-z]\w*|\d+) *\) *
```

Have a look at the [updated regex](https://regex101.com/r/aL0zC7/3)

I mainly added a quantifier `+` to `[=<>]+`, and removed anchors `^` and `$` for better visualization (you may revert them if you test individual strings).

I replaced `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` with `\w` (they are identical), and `[0-9]` with almost identical `\d`. Case insensitive `i` option should work well with `[a-z]` character class.

If you also plan to add `!=` support, try:

```
 *while +\( *([a-z]\w*) *((?:!=|[=<>]=?)) *([a-z]\w*|\d+) *\) *
```

[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/aL0zC7/4)

Comment: Thank you @stribizhev. But it will also match this `while (a =<=> 5) ` for example. This is an error, and I want it to match only the cases mentioned above

Comment: Please have a look now.

Comment: Thanks @stribizhev. It works now. Thanks for making my regexp shorter too.

Comment: You are welcome. Also, have a look at another suggestion for `!=` support.

Comment: Thanks. I have forgoten that case. Can I make you a question? Why is `?:` use in front of `!=`?

Comment: `(?:)` is a non-capturing group. I did not want to mess your original capturing group order.

Answer (score 0):

Does this regex work for you?

```
^ *while +\( *([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*) *([=<>]{1,2}) *([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*|[0-9]+) *\) *$
```

All I did was add a check for 1 or 2 of the operators `{1,2}`. Unless i'm misunderstanding this should work.