# How to make "print" statement to print multiple strings Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, interpreter

I am trying to make a small interpreter for print statement. Here is a demo of what I have done till now: 
[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/orsina/cht21z4p/4/)

What I want to reach now is to print multiple string connected with `+`like:

- print "My book" + "is" + "xx"
- print a  (where a is varible name)
- print a + "is my number"

I have tried something till now and build something but I have two problems:

1. First I tried to build a new print regexp:

   `/^ *print +(?:"([^"]*)"|([a-zA-Z]\w*)) *(.*)$/`

so this will match the print statement, the first argument could be a string("") or a variable name. And then with `(.*)` I am trying to catch all other variables or strings and to use them later. ( I have in mind to build a while loop). 
But my problem is that when I make the match it outputs me an empty value. So when I make `alert(t)` the `t[2]` value is empty(,,).

2. The second problem is that I am not able to test if the first parameter of print is a varible or a string. I tried this:
   `t1 = t[1].match(rxString);` but it output null ( because in fact it search for `""`, but when saved in `(t)` they are removed from the string)

Here is my [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/orsina/ffjkecb7/)

Please can you help me how to solve this this?  Thanks in advance

Comment: I would suggest you to use a Javascript Parser Generator like [PEG.js](http://pegjs.org) to achieve what you want...

Answer (score 0):

Building interpreters with only regexes is between difficult and impossible. You might rather tokenize your input (e.g. split at white spaces + before/after some selected special characters) and then detect and handle each token individually.

If you want to go more complex you should of course define a grammar for your language and match that using a library like PEG.js as @peter-schneider pointed out.

You should be able to detect string literals quite easily by whether the token starts with a `"` or `'`:

```
if (token[0] == '"' || token[1] == '\'') { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Thanks @opatut. I fact i was trying to build it with regexes. But culd you recomment me any good documentation and practical  example where I start learning peg.js? despite the documentation I find on its website?